# JavaScript Web Worker - close() vs terminate()

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm not totally understanding the difference between the close() vs terminate() methods for Web Workers. I've read the descriptions here and it seems to be doing the same thing??
http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/

When would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `close()` method is visible inside the worker's scope.
The `terminate()` method is a part of the worker object's interface and can be called "from the outside".

If you create a worker in your main script and want to stop it from that script you should call the `terminate()` on the worker object. If you want to stop the worker from the worker code (for example as a response to an external message) you should call the `close()` method.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Terminating_a_worker

Comment: Is it possible to check if the worker is still alive/running?

Comment: @Ωmega Sadly you cannot check if a worker is still running: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044817/how-can-i-know-if-a-web-worker-has-closed

Comment: Terminate also "Aborts worker's associated global environment." which I assume would nullify all its event listeners, meaning it won't respond to any messages you send it anymore. Once you `terminate()` a worker, I don't think you can make use of it anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Other differences when you use web worker in React:

1. if you use `terminate`, you just call the api, and it is `synchronous`
2. if you use `close`, you need to call `postMessage` and send a signal/message so that the worker can kill itself inside its scope. `postMessage` is `NOT` synchronous, as far as I know.

The problem of `close` is that if want to kill the worker when you `unmount` a component, you need to do it `synchronously`, otherwise, you `may` get a warning, especially when you try to clean up things in the `ComponentWillUnmount` lifecycle hook or `useEffect` hook (otherwise, there will be multiple zombie web worker instances alive).

The warning looks like:

`Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

OR:

`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

Answer (score 2):

I found a good use case for self.close() over terminate. Inside my web worker I had a setInterval function that was receiving and posting back an objects position.  Using terminate kills the web worker for good, so I could not send the play message back to the worker. Meanwhile closing it, allowed me re open it and restart the timer.

Answer (score 2):

hmm, simply.

```
// immediately terminate the main JS file
worker.terminate();
// stop the worker from the worker code.
self.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the **close()** function is visible from inside the scope of the Worker.

**terminate()** is visible from outside (i.e: the script that calls the worker can shut it down using this function)

TBH this is a little bit confusing at first, but once you implemented you will get used to it