# How can i know if a web worker has closed?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

HTML5 Workers can close themselves by calling the **close()** method.

Is there a way to tell if the worker process is alive/running or if it has been closed?

```
var myWorker = new Worker("worker.js");

...

if( myWorker.isAlive() ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Current specification for web Workers does not allow for parent page to check whether the WebWorker is still alive without explicit worker cooperation (i.e. responding to PING message). Huge deficiency in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of the [Web Locks API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Locks_API) you can make the worker hold a lock for its entire life. When the worker is terminated the browser [should release the lock](https://w3c.github.io/web-locks/#termination-of-locks). You can then poll this by calling `navigator.locks.query()`, or by trying to acquire the lock.

There are a few footguns to this approach:

1. Lock names are per origin, not per browsing context; if you choose a static name for your lock and your app is open in multiple tabs/windows it will break.
2. There is a time between when the `Worker` in constructed and when it acquires it's lock during which you cannot tell if its running.
3. Locks require a secure context, so no data url workers or restrictive iframes.
4. Holding a lock prevents the worker from being automatically closed by the garbage collector. [w3c/web-locks#107](https://github.com/w3c/web-locks/issues/107)

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdwhov24/) with a very basic implementation of this. (Stack Exchange snippets are too restrictive to use the Lock API).

Comment: You can use the [`name`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#concept-workerglobalscope-name) WorkerOption instead of the `location.hash` hack. And it seems that this prevents the auto-closing of the Worker (when it can't receive new messages from the outside, nor has anything to do). At least on Firefox they do close it soon enough without the lock, but never when it's there. I'm still waiting on Chrome to close it even when there is no lock, so there the test is compromised. That's probably a huge "footgun" for the ones relying on that behavior.

Comment: That's actually https://github.com/w3c/web-locks/issues/107

Comment: That is good to know, I edited it into the answer. I preferred using the url fragment over the worker's name so I can put something useful in the name to show in devtools, and not a random uuid.

Answer (score 0):

The worker itself won't tell you, but you have two options:

1. You can put something in the script it's running. For example, a boolean `isRunning`:

Example:

```
function myScript()
{
    isRunning = true;
    ...do stuff...
    isRunning = false;
}
```

Then have a function running in `setInterval` or `setTimeout` (that calls self repeatedly) that checks for that value.

You'll also want to handle errors `try...catch` so you can set it to `false` when an error ends your code.

2. You can use `postMessage` and send a request to your script that will tell you if it's still running.

Example:

```
//Make sure we have a listener
myWorker.addEventListener( 'message', checkIsRunning );

//Now ask
myWorker.postMessage( { request: MyWorker.IS_RUNNING } );

//The worker would have something like:
self.onmessage = function (msg) {
    switch (msg.data.aTopic) {
    case MyWorker.IS_RUNNING:
        self.postMessage( { aTopic: isRunning } );
        break;
    default:
        throw 'no aTopic on incoming message to ChromeWorker';
    }
}
```

Note that with *both* options, neither one tells you whether the Worker object is dead (it's not), as it is **always** still able to respond to messages until you call `terminate();`

If you instead want to capture whenever the `close()` function is called, save that in your worker when it's first run:

```
myWorker._selfClose = self.close;
```

And then call that inside your overridden close function:

```
close: function()
{
    //Mark it as no longer running
    this.isRunning = false;

    //Call original close function
    this._selfClose();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but i think that in the scenario where there is no way to tell if the worker is dead or not from the Worker object, the correct architecture would be to never close the worker using **close()** directly, but to simply use function that gives the info to the main thread first, then call **close()**. It seems more convenient to use than the two options above.

Comment: @Sebastien That's incorrect. My first example works perfectly. Just have your code set `isRunning = false` only if `.close()` is called. You can then check that. (And you can override `close()` in your worker by saving the original close: `myWorker._selfClose = self.close;` and then calling that inside your overridden close function: `close: function() { this.isRunning = false; this._selfClose(); }`

Comment: I don't understand how the overriden `close()` can work. If you set a local variable in the worker `this.isRunning = false` then call the close function `this._selfClose()`, the worker will close itself **without warning the main thread** (even if the main thread has some checks running with setInterval). But calling postMessage at this time may work better: `close: function() { self.postMessage({ 'cmd', 'closing' }); this._selfClose(); }`, but we still need to guarantee that the main thread won't perform worker operations before receiving the close msg (possible race conditions otherwise).