# How to stop js web worker from within?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

TLDR: What is an alternative to `WorkerGlobalScope.close()` which is not [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/close#Browser_compatibility)

I want to close/stop/terminate a Javascript web worker from the inside, after its job is done, since there is a `setInterval()` which keeps being active even after the main work is done.

Reading this SO question ([JavaScript Web Worker - close() vs terminate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500883/javascript-web-worker-close-vs-terminate)), it seems like `self.close()` is what I'm searching for. But apparently this is deprecated (stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/close#Browser_compatibility)) without any mention of alternatives.

The only alternative I have come up with so far would be to send a message to the main thread which then invokes a `worker.terminate()` call, but that seems like overkill since I would then need to check every message that comes this way for a termination request.

Am I missing something? What should I use?

Comment: You could use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` and when it's time to stop simply do not initiate the next timer call.

Comment: Interesting workaround, thx for the idea, however not really what I had in mind :D

Comment: Can just kill the `setInterval` with `clearInterval`?

Comment: Thanks, it solves a part of the problem, like the answer of Pointy. However I would still prefer a solution to stop all the worker reliably at any time and also halfway through the script. Also I'd like to not worry about all functions & intervals I need to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notice is misleading `.close()` is not deprecated at all.

What happens here is that in the specs [`WorkerGlobalScope`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#workerglobalscope) is an interface that is used by different worker types (DedicatedWorkers, ServiceWorkers, SharedWorkers, and maybe other Worklets in other specs).
All these types don't have a `.close` method (e.g [ServiceWorkers](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#serviceworkerglobalscope) don't), and thus this method has been moved to each specific types of worker global scope's definition.

For instance you can see that for the [DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#dedicatedworkerglobalscope), it's still here, and isn't scheduled to be deprecated any time soon.

And it's actually [also there in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope/close).

Comment: I opened https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/1694